# Fitbit integration not getting refresh token

Tags: android, fitbit

I am developing one fitness app in android. I want to add my app workout data on Fitbit. I was successfully login in Fitbit using oAuth 2.0 My url is as below:

```
https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id="
        + clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri + "&scope=" + scope
```

and I'm getting below response:

```
callback://android-****#scope=activity&user_id=*****&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=86152&access_token=***************HAiOjE0NjAxMTI3MjUsInNjb3BlcyI6IndhY3QiLCJzdWIiOiI0NjZTNzIiLCJhdWQiOiIyMjdIWDgiLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0NjAwMjY1NzN9.KV3zV0QjNHv0nmFAxGzd6OUp*********
```

I'm not getting refresh token. How I will refresh access token ? Please guide me where I am wrong or missing something.

Thanks

Comment: I have upgraded one of the sample projects on fitbit oAuth 2.0 integration as well as data parsing from their web api. Hopefully you will find your desired answer if you go through the whole project at https://github.com/Asad-noor/FitbitTestApi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the implicit grant flow. The Implicit Grant Flow doesn't use refresh tokens and the user must re-authorize the application when the access token expires.

You may be looking for the [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/#authorization-code-grant-flow).

Comment: I tried with : String url = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id="
                       + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_url + "&scope=" + scope;

and not getting success response either.

Comment: "The App you are trying to connect did not provide valid information  to fitbit. Please report this issue to them." : This is the error test

Comment: @DeepPatel Did you create an app in Fitbit console?